# Merge logs by timestamps

Tags: logs, log-analysis

I need a tool that can show two (ideally = N) log files as a single stream merging them according timestamps. Those timestamps, generally speaking, could be in different formats and ideally it would be nice to have an opportunity to configure how timestamps are fetched.

**Preferences:**

- Free is better then something proprietary
- *nix-like is more preferable than pure Linux solution (i.e. MacOS is very not obligatory but it is awesome if it is supported. Linux is more preferable than Windows.
- CLI is more preferable than GUI.

Lack of any of this features is not a blocker per se though.

As of timestamp format - it should be customizable. Something like, don't know, `--timestamps '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', %Y-%m-%d %H:%MM:%ss'`.

Comment: What OS must the tool run on? What kind of log formats must be supported? Do you have any budget you're willing to spend, or must the tool be free (as in "free beer")? Any license restrictions to take care of (e.g. commercial use/educational use)? Please [edit] your question and include those data. The better details you give, the closer answers can match :)

Comment: are you open to hosted solutions? A SaaS solution would probably save you the time of setting this whole thing up.

Comment: @Izzy all good point, will edit my question now, thank you for helpful hints.

Comment: @shabunc Thanks for the good edit! But it's still lacking the price/license part :) And note that "free" and "proprietary" are not necessarily counter-parts, something can be free and proprietary, or even paid and open-source (you get the source, but need to pay for a binary distribution; several Android apps use this model, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Try [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 log1 log2 ...
```

It will print the passed log files contents, sorting log messages by datetime. `s4` can recognize many datetime formats.